# Intellisense says the property does not exist in Class1 and Class2

Tags: typescript

Here is my code, i know that is a bit long but not hard to understand.
It showing error in the last line and also losing intellisense there. 
"Property 'test' does not exist on type 'Test | Test2'."
As you can see clearly the 'test' property is obviously within the 'Test' class. So what's wrong?

```
class Test{
    test: string = 'test';
}
class Test2{
    test2: string = 'test2';
}

function isTest(obj: Test|Test2): obj is Test{
    if(obj instanceof Test)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}

function test(obj: Test|Test2): Test|Test2{
    if(isTest(obj))
    return obj as Test;
    else
    return obj as Test2;
}



let varTest: Test = new Test();
console.log(test(varTest).test); //this line is broken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **Why it's not working**

The return type of `test()` is static in the sense that it's return value will **always** be `Test | Test2`, regardless of how it's called. This means that `varTest` can be `Test` OR `Test2` (which does not contain a `test` property), so the error is correctly letting you know that the property you are trying to access may not exist.

If we need a dynamic return type, we need to turn to generics, overloads, or conditional types, depending on the problem. In your case, we can use function overloads.

#### **Working solution**

[**Function overloads**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) allow you to specify return types that are conditional on the input types. To make your `test()` function work as expected, we overload it with two conditions: one for `Test` and another for `Test2`:

```
function test(obj: Test): Test; // given Test, return Test
function test(obj: Test2): Test2; // given Test2, return Test2
function test(obj: Test | Test2): Test | Test2{
    if(isTest(obj))
        return obj as Test;
    else
        return obj as Test2;
}

let varTest: Test = new Test();
console.log(test(varTest).test); // OK

let varTest2: Test2 = new Test2();
console.log(test(varTest2).test); // Error! 'test' does not exist in Test2
```

See [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test%3A%20string%20%3D%20'test'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Test2%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test2%3A%20string%20%3D%20'test2'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isTest(obj%3A%20Test%7CTest2)%3A%20obj%20is%20Test%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(obj%20instanceof%20Test)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(obj%3A%20Test)%3A%20Test%3B%0D%0Afunction%20test(obj%3A%20Test2)%3A%20Test2%3B%0D%0Afunction%20test(obj%3A%20Test%7CTest2)%3A%20Test%7CTest2%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if(isTest(obj))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obj%20as%20Test%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20obj%20as%20Test2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20varTest%3A%20Test%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test(varTest).test)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%20%3A)%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20varTest2%3A%20Test2%20%3D%20new%20Test2()%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test(varTest2).test)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error!%20'test'%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20Test2).

Answer (score 0):

@Dakito, this typescript Union type is quite tricky.

But if you take a look here: [Typescript Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) you can see you will have to add a check to make sure you are safely accessing a field or method from an object without assuming it will not fail.

```
// this line is broken
let varTest: Test = new Test();

let testResult: Test | Test2 = test(varTest);

// Adding these checks here will help you safely access the correct values.
// You can also improve this code by using User-Defined Type Guards
if(<Test>testResult.test) {
    console.log((<Test>testResult).test);
} else if(<Test2>testResult.test2) {
    console.log((<Test2>testResult).test2);
}
```